# Magento multi currency cache issue

Tags: magento

We are integrating international checkout in Magento. Customers can see products in their local currency. But the issue is currency is get cached. For eg : If somebody browse from India, that page will show in INR. If somebody browse same page from US, it should show in $. But due to caching it will show in INR. I know this can be fixed using cache hole punch. Can you tell us which block we need to hole punch. Appreciate if you can guide me on this.

Comment: Have you fixed this? I have the same problem.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243700/magento2-full-page-cache-issue-with-multiple-currencies

Answer (score 0):

you will need a GeoIp module.

A good resource can be found here: https://www.atwix.com/magento/geoip-magento-store-switcher/

First you'll have to install the GitHub module: https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/Sandfox_GeoIP

Then you will have to synchronize the IP database under **System Configuration->General->Countries Options**

From that point you will need to create your own module with the following helper:

```
/* app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/Helper/Data.php */
class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const DEFAULT_STORE = 'English';

    /**
     * countries to store relation
     * default is English
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_countryToStore = array(
        'US' => 'sv2',
        'IN' => 'sv1'
    );

    /**
     * get store view name by country
     * @param $country
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getStoreByCountry($country)
    {
        if (isset($this->_countryToStore[$country])) {
            return $this->_countryToStore[$country];
        }
        return self::DEFAULT_STORE;
    }
}
```

Then you will need to observer the `controller_action_postdipatch` event to redirect your customers:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/etc/config.xml-->       
<config>
 ...
    <global>
    ...
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch>
                <observers>
                    <atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                        <class>atwix_ipstoreswitcher/observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPostdispatch</method>
                    </atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Finally your observer:

```
/* app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/Model/Observer.php */

class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * redirects customer to store view based on GeoIP
     * @param $event
     */
    public function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)
    {
        $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
        if ($cookie->get('geoip_processed') != 1) {
            $geoIPCountry = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
            $countryCode = $geoIPCountry->getCountry();
            if ($countryCode) {
                $storeName = Mage::helper('atwix_ipstoreswitcher')->getStoreByCountry($countryCode);
                if ($storeName) {
                    $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeName, 'code');
                    if ($store->getName() != Mage::app()->getStore()->getName()) {
                        $event->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($store->getCurrentUrl(false));
                    }
                }
            }
            $cookie->set('geoip_processed', '1', time() + 86400, '/');
        }
    }
}
```

chnage your store name according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. We have only one store, but giving option to choose customer's country and price will display in their local currency.

Comment: if you dont want different languages than, you can create multiple store-views for one country and you can use different price & currency for each store - view.

Comment: @Rajeevan Did you found solution, if so please accept the answer.